# Dealing with users entering strings in C (error handling)

Tags: c

Ok so I am building a program, it asks the user how high should a half pyramid be and the user then enters an integer ranging for 1-24 (I have a do while loop in place if they enter integers outside this range).

The program then goes on to build the half pyramid.  My problem is if the user enters a character or string basically anything that isn't a number the program will crash and I have searched all over but still can not find a solution to apply in my case.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
     int height; //user inputs this
     int counter;
     int line;

     do
     {
        printf("What height should the half pyramid be?\n");
        scanf("%d", &height);

        printf("You typed in %d\n", height);

        if(height > 23 || height<1)
        {
            printf("The half pyramid must be no bigger than 23 and higher than 0 buddy\n");
        }
    }
    while(height >23 || height<1);

    for(line = 1; line <= height; line++)
    {
        int spaceNum = height - line;
        int spaceCounter;

        for (spaceCounter = 0; spaceCounter <= spaceNum ; spaceCounter++)
            printf(" ");

        for(counter = 0; counter < line ; counter++)
            printf("#");

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it actually *crash*, or just *freeze* / infinite loop? I don't see anything in this code that would make it actually *crash* under any circumstances.

Comment: please choose a good name acoording to your post. thank you.

Comment: It sends the program into an infinite loop (sorry should of said that instead of crash)

Answer (score 1):

Read in a string and the parse the string using sscanf. Check the sscanf return for how many fields were successfully read from it.

Comment: Could you give me some code example on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check the return value from `scanf`.

Should return 1. If not it has not read an integer. So you need to eat some buffer. i.e. a string up to new line and throw it away and ask again

Comment: Adding to this, before "searching all over", reading the documentation for the functions you are using (`scanf` in this case) is worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the entered input to the `strtol` function, which will return the input as a long integer. If the input is not a valid number, `0` is returned. If the value is out of range, the function returns `LONG_MAX` or `LONG_MIN` (defined in `limits.h`), and errno is set to `ERANGE`.
 Perform a conditional test so that the program displays an 'invalid input' message and asks for the number again if it receives a `0`.

Source: [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)

Comment: atoi has "undefined behaivour" if the number in the string contains a number greater than an int. I wouldn't use it on user supplied data.

Comment: If he is to use `strtol` he will also have to declare a `char` buffer and read a line or partial line, and also handle the case when the user types more on the same line than the size of his buffer.  (This is probably a good plan, I'm just filling in some details for OP)

Comment: I suppose there's a way to determine the size/length of input before reading it into the buffer, but I don't have enough experience with C to provide the code for that.

Comment: This answer makes a lot of sense to me but it is way over my head to code it

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `scanf()`, use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` or `strtol()`

```
// scanf("%d", &height);
char buf[40];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &height) != 1) Handle_InputError();
```

Comment: So does the fgets act the same way as scanf?  I just don't understand how to fit this inside my code, i understand that but don't know how to code it

Comment: @NewCoder2k14 `fgets()` gets a line of text up to the size specified (minus 1) or unitla a `\n` is encountered.  Then use `sscanf()` to parse that string as desired like `sscanf(buf, "%d", ...` or use whatever format needed to tear apart the string.  The above code replaces your `scanf("%d", &height);`.  The `Handle_InputError();` is simply code you write should user enter text like "abc" when a number is requested.  Maybe just exit your program then.